# deployment asp.net webforms in iis i got no Css style at all

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, iis

i made one page asp.net as login and 
here how it looks like:-
[image]

after i made publish to it as file system and put the out put files on IIS
[image]
note that i followed this  [Youtube video](http://%20youtube.com/watch?v=-ymjT8C-tHc) to deploy my web app , is there is a problem in my implementation or a missing step 
thanks  in advance

Answer (score 0):

In your Project Open Css Folder if you have then select all .css file ==> Properties ==> Copy if newer ==> Clean and Build your project again and create a Publish execution.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes it was one of 2 problems the second was that i forgot to add "/" at the end of link tag , now it works

Answer (score 0):

2 Things:

1 - Run Fiddler, or use F12 tools in IE, Firefox or Chrome, use the networking tools and determine the HTTP status code when the CSS is trying to load.  404 tells you the files aren't at the correct path of the requested directory, 401 tells you unauthorized.

2 - If you're receiving 401 (unauthorized), Check the authorization settings of your CSS directory.  If your site is not setup for anonymous access (aka meaning you need to log into the site to browse), you need to specify unauthorized users have access to the appropriate files\directories.

For example, in your web.config:

```
<location path="path/to/my/styles">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```